# Java JLabel - add a unique identifier

Tags: java, jlabel

Is there anyway to add an ID or a unique identifier to a JLabel?

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JLabel has a setName method that is inherited from java.awt.Component. You could use this for an ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Component.setName` on it, or `JComponent.putClientProperty`, or subclass or use the `JLabel` object as a key is a `Map` of some sort.

But probably the way to go is to keep hold of a reference to the original object, so you can write clean, direct code that doesn't have to look the component up.